# type of keyboard inside an activity

Tags: android, keyboard

Some apps containing edittext, use the default keybord that have a sort of tab button instead return button.
There's a way to call it inside my app instead the classic one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try this attribute in your EditText

```
 android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

Comment: While reading the api, i think "actionNext" attributes should be perfect fot my target, but the keyboard still have the enter button instead next button

Comment: Ok, now it works. The actionNext require a single line edit text